# What is the average cost of satellite construction over the last 10 years?

Tags: launch, artificial-satellite, cost

In the last 10 years what was the Highest and lowest, construction cost of satellites launched?  What are the mean and average costs of satellite construction over the same period?

Where "a" Satellite is a single device capable of communicating with Earth or other satellites and is physically separated from other bodies in orbit by design.

Where cost and launch numbers are calculated based on both figures being available.

Comment: This is a very broad range, the cost for building a satellite depends on an extraordinarily large array of questions...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: Still, a min/max/avg would be a perfectly viable metric which would give us a rough clue... except costs of most of commercial satellites are a trade secret and costs of military satellites are a state secret, leaving only a relatively small margin of scientific satellites open to public. The question is good, just the data is not available.

Comment: An average across all satellites isn't really all that useful of a metric. It's something akin to asking the average price of an airplane. Are you talking about a large commercial plane, or a small 2 seat plane? A cross cut average doesn't really mean much including both sets.

Comment: I don't believe this question is overly broad. Satellites and Automobiles are both part of daily life, both have huge differences in the cost between units, there are multiple variations for different customer bases. They are used by civilian and military. The metric for cars is available on [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/story/money/cars/2013/09/04/record-price-new-car-august/2761341/).  Both airplane and satellites have a lot more secrets in their pricing so it more difficult to get the answer, but that does not make the metric less valuable, just more difficult to get.

Comment: It is well known that Russian tanks are always in the price range of a very good meat or an expensive sausage. Today T-90 is approx. 1000 rubles per kilo. There always exists an answer.